# Jenkins build multibranch pipeline from another multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have Jenkins setup with 2 `multibranch` pipeline which depend on each other let say `multibranchPipelineA` and `multibranchPipelineB`. I would like a job from `multibranchPipelineA` to build specific branch in `multibranchPipelineA` and wait the build to finish

I have tried use below from `multibranchPipeleA` `Jenkinfile`

```
stage('Build MiniApp Libs') {
            steps {
                build(
                    job: "../multibranchPipeleB/master",
                    propagate: true,
                    wait: true
                )
            }
        }
```

But always receive `No item named ../multibranchPipeleB/master` found.

If I use single pipeline, let's say `pipelineB`, then the below work
`../pipelineB`

How can I build specific branch `multibranchPipeline` from another `multibranchPipeline` jobs? and wait the build to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build another `multibranchPipeline` you do not need `..` before its name. So in your case just use:

`job: "multibranchPipeleB/master"`

Comment: hi thanks for your help, i have change to
```build(
                    job: "ami-ph-android-gcashapp/master",
                    propagate: true,
                    wait: true
                )```
i still get error `No item named ami-ph-android-gcashapp/master` seem like jenkins cannot find the multibranch pipeline

Comment: When you open your multibranch pipeline and you branch in Jenkins UI, there should be a field named `Full project name: `. Does this name match with the name you are trying to build?

Comment: e.g. as on this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WAef.png

Comment: thanks, get it to work, my mistake is branch master is never been built that why jenkins can not find. i trigger a build on master from (multibranch piple to create master branch job)